# Subtraction between rows in a time column

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, time

I have a csv file and i filtered it into two columns one of them has timestamp values and the other is numbers
I want to make a loop that loops over the rows of the file to sum the values of the second column for all the times within the same second in the first column of times
I have an issue dealing with time and also with the algorithm itself
Here is one of the trials i have:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=Input_filtered) #This is a dataframe of the file with only the 2 columns

for i in range(0,Input_filtered_size,1):
        row1, row2 = df.iloc[i], df.iloc[i+1]
        if row2['Time'] - row1['Time'] <= 1: #Iam not sure if comparing the time difference with 1 is right or not 
            df.iloc[i] = (row2['Number of Samples'] + row1['Number of Samples'])
```

Edit: Sample of the two columns

```
Time    Length
11:53:59    1
11:53:59    2
11:53:59    3
11:53:59    4
11:53:59    5
11:54:00    6
11:54:00    7
11:54:00    8
11:54:00    9
```

And so on
What i need to do is to sum all of the samples that have the same time in seconds so the suggested output will be:

```
Time    Length
11:53:59    15
11:54:00    30
```

Comment: post the sample data and expected output

Comment: you can see it now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.groupby('Time')['Length'].sum().reset_index()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    Time    Length
0   11:53:59    15
1   11:54:00    30
```

Comment: It did nothing to the dataframe

Comment: did you check what it is printing

Comment: yes it is printing the same input ans i can see that from the size as well

Comment: can you share the code i will check is there any problem